# SIGABRT (signal 6) error in finding majority element in array using divide and conquer

Tags: c++, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I checked SO and saw two issues dealing with the same problem statement. However, neither of them contained what I'm looking for. The task is to output 1 if an array with *n* elements contains an element that occurs more than *n/2* times, using a *divide and conquer strategy*.

I developed what I think is a working solution based on the fact that the base case is a sub array with one element that is (obviously) the majority element in the subarray. I then proceed to compare these majority elements across subarrays, asking if ultimately they happen more than *n/2* times.

For more details, see https://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps102/Fall01/solutions4.pdf (Problem 4)

I wrote two different solutions to this problem, one using a very naive O(n^2) algorithm to check if my solution was correct for all cases, and one attempting to implement the algorithm described in the link above.

Inside main, I stress test my solution against the obviously correct but naive one. However, upon running this I'm getting a SIGABRT (signal 6) error. My debugger tells me to check for malloc, object was probably modified after being freed.

Now I can't tell whether or not my solution is correct. I really don't know what's going on with bad allocation, I'm relatively new to C++.

Code goes below:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

int get_majority_element(vector<int> &a, int left, int right) {


    int m;
    int majority_left, majority_right;      // majority element in either sub array
    int count_right = 0, count_left = 0;    // count for above
    int leftt, rightt;                      // endpoints

    if (a.size() == 1) {
        return a[0];
    }
    else {

        m = (left + right)/2;  // calculate mid point

        vector<int> b_left(m);
        vector<int> b_right(right - m);


        // get left sub array
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            b_left[i] = a[i];
        }

        // set new endpoints
        leftt = 0;
        rightt = m;

        majority_left = get_majority_element(b_left, leftt, rightt);

        for (int i = 0; i < right - m + 1; i++) {
            b_right[i] = a[m+i];
        }

        leftt = m;
        rightt = right - m + 1;

        majority_right = get_majority_element(b_right, leftt, rightt);

        // if there is a majority element, count its frequency

        if (majority_left != -1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
                if (a[i] == majority_left)
                    count_left++;
            }
        }

        if (majority_right != -1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
                if (a[i] == majority_right)
                    count_right++;
            }
        }


        // if both elements in sub arrays are majority and they're different, there is no majority element
        if (count_left == count_right && majority_left != majority_right) {
            return -1;
        }

        // check if either sub array has a majority element that occurs more than n/2 times
        else if (count_right > count_left && count_right > a.size()/2) {
                return majority_right;
        }
        else if (count_left > count_right && count_left > a.size()/2){
            return majority_left;
        }
    }

    return -1;

}


int get_majority_fast(vector<int> &a, int left, int right){

    std::reverse(a.begin(),a.end());

    int current = 0;
    int count;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        current = a[i];
        count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++) {
            if (a[j] == current)
                count ++;
        }
        if (count > a.size()/2)
            return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() {
//    std::cin >> n;
//    vector<int> a(n);
//    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
//        std::cin >> a[i];
//    }
//    std::cout << (get_majority_fast(a, 0, a.size()) != -1) << '\n';

    while(true){
        int one, two;
        int n = rand() % 100 ;
        std::cout << n << "\n";
        vector<int> a;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            a.push_back(rand() % 100);
        }

        one = get_majority_element(a, 0, a.size());
        two = get_majority_fast(a,  0, a.size() != -1);

        if (one != two) {
            std::cout << "Wrong answer: " << one << ' ' << two << "\n";
            break;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "OK\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't `get_majority_fast()` use the `left` or `right` arguments? And why are you passing a boolean as the `right` argument?

Comment: Run the program under the debugger. When it stops because of the error, check the stack trace to see what statement got the error, and what the values of the variables are. It's probably because you're accessing outside the vector.

Comment: One of the best debugging tools when you use `std::vector` is to use the `at()` function.  It will throw an exception if you ever go out-of-bounds of the vector.  You do so right here:  `b_right[i] = a[m + i];` -- change this to `b_right[i] = a.at(m + i)` and you should get an `std::out_of_range` exception [just as this example shows](http://ideone.com/CdXM7T)

Comment: @Barmar, I wrote `get_majority_fast` rather quickly so I just copy-pasted the function definition from the one before. The arguments getting passed to it are irrelevant though. I'll check for out of bounds, thanks.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Can you please provide an input under which this happens? I had been getting correct outputs so far without any out-of-bounds exceptions (using `a[m+i]`)

Comment: @EmilioBotero -- That's the problem.  When you use `[ ]` to access a vector's item, it is undefined behavior to access an item out-of-bounds.  There is no guarantee the program will crash, even though the program is wrong.  Using `at()` **guarantees** the program stops on an out-of-bounds access.  I used no test data -- I just used the program you posted and ran it with the small change by using `at()`.  So in a nutshell, your program was always wrong, but you never knew it, and were fooled by seeing output showing up.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Somewhere in the back of my mind I knew about `a.at()`. From Python I'm used to using `[ ]`, though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There was effectively an out of bounds error in one of the loops. Corrected loop is below:

```
for (int i = m; i < right - m ; i++) {
    b_right.at(m-i) = a.at(m + i);
}
```

I thought the weird SIGABRT error was due to something arcane. Guess I learned to use `x.at()`

Also, I had a couple other mistakes. Full corrected code is below:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using std::vector;

int get_majority_element(vector<int> &a, int left, int right) {


    int m;
    int majority_left = -1, majority_right = -1;      // majority element in either sub array
    int count_right = 0, count_left = 0;    // count for above
    int new_left, new_right;                      // endpoints

    if (a.size() == 1) {
        return a[0];
    }
    else {


        m = (a.size())/2;  // calculate mid point

        vector<int> b_left(m);
        vector<int> b_right(right - m);


        // get left sub array
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            b_left.at(i) = a.at(i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.size() - m ; i++) {
            b_right.at(i) = a.at(i + m);
        }

        // set new endpoints
        new_left = 0;
        new_right = m;
        majority_left = get_majority_element(b_left, new_left, new_right);


        new_left = m;
        new_right = right - m;

        majority_right = get_majority_element(b_right, new_left, new_right);


        // if there is a majority element, count its frequency

        if (majority_left != -1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
                if (a[i] == majority_left)
                    count_left++;
            }
        }

        if (majority_right != -1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
                if (a[i] == majority_right)
                    count_right++;
            }
        }


        // if both elements in sub arrays are majority and they're different, there is no majority element
        if (count_left == count_right && majority_left != majority_right) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (count_left == count_right)
            return majority_left;
        // check if either sub array has a majority element that occurs more than n/2 times
        else if (count_right > count_left && count_right > a.size()/2) {
                return majority_right;
        }
        else if (count_left > count_right && count_left > a.size()/2){
            return majority_left;
        }
            // majority element in sub arrays isn't majority in array
        else
            return 0;
    }

}


int get_majority_fast(vector<int> &a, int left, int right){

    std::reverse(a.begin(),a.end());

    int current = 0;
    int count;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        current = a[i];
        count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++) {
            if (a[j] == current)
                count ++;
        }
        if (count > a.size()/2)
            return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() {

    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        std::cin >> a[i];
    }

    int result;
    int out;

    result = get_majority_element(a, 0, a.size());

    if (result != 0)
        out = 1;
    else
        out = 0;
    std::cout << out << '\n';


}
```

I'm sure I could make it a lot prettier but right now I don't want to hear about this for a while.